# shell isolated with new language done with ANTLR

Tags: visual-studio-2010, shell, sdk, antlr, ironpython

I want to create an IDE. I have an Isolated Shell application with VSIX Project for IntelliSense, and another VSIX Project for Syntax color. In the Isolated Shell application, I want to add a template, if that's possible.

I have the example of IronPython VS2010 Isolated Shell, but I don't understand how it works very well. In my work I have the language done with ANTLR, and for that language I need to create the IDE.

I know there are many questions, and I don't know if I could explain well, but any questions or assistance, or if you can refer to somewhere that provides this information, I would appreciate it.

Comment: You may want to look at [Xtext](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but Xtext is what they are using now, and they want to change it because it does not work well. Thanks.